# Solr grouping and facets

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I started to work with Solr but have some problems. The problem is that i have a document which contains data about persons. The document can contains two or multiple times the same persons. I found out that i can use the so called FieldCollapsing for grouping my results and this is working fine. For example i have a document with 104 persons whereby 78 entries are double so my grouping result is 26.

Now I want to know how many of this 26 persons are male or female and there starts my problem if I add group.query and include there to group on the gender i get as result integer 1 back. How can I get the values of male and female? Do I need to make a second query or can i modify my query?

If you need more information or code just let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I have dealt with the same problem before, however with the large number of documents in the index, getting the unique facet numbers will be a bit slower than just getting the whole number.

What you need to do is adding group.facet=true to the url or the defaults in solrconfig:

```
<lst name="defaults">
    <str name="group">true</str>
    <str name="group.field">PersonId</str>  <!-- Group by your person id here -- >
    <str name="group.facet">true</str>  <!-- this is what you are after -->
</lst>
```